# Implementing TOTP algorithm on JAVA

Tags: java

I wanted to implement this algorithm but I am struggling with writing the function that calculates the unix time for UTC time (not local time). For example,

```
Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

returns unix time according to my local time. But how can I make it work for UTC time? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So to be able to get the epoch time in java you would have to use  System.currentTimeMillis()
And then dividing this number by 1000 will result in the Unix epoch. A call like this would suffice.

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```